# Skip empty GET params in the URL (Laravel 4)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a listing with some filters which are applied on form submit, using GET as form method. So after submit, I get a url that looks like:

```
/listing?filter_1=a&filter_2=&filter_3=c
```

Notice that `filter_2` is empty. How can I avoid showing it in the URL in this case? I would only need the URL to be like this:

```
/listing?filter_1=a&filter_3=c
```

I would not mess with `$_GET` and I wonder what is the right way to do it with Laravel 4.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During making of url, you need to check the value of variables whether it has empty or null or have some value. Then add those varibale into the url, so that your url will be clean.

Answer (score 0):

to achive this you will be required to use **Laravel - pretty URls** functionality and make some changes in **Route::get** function to remove empty parameters while construction url.